# delete path not found , store proxy wrong?

Tags: javascript, extjs

i´m new to extjs and i´m facing a problem where i realy don´t understand why it´s not working. i´m trying to delete a row from my grid and the database where the grid is populated , but my client say that there is no delete on my server (sorry for bad english)

here is my code :

store:

```
Ext.define('LU.store.Audios', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',       
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'LU.model.Audio',

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',

            api: {
                create: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',
                read: 'http://localhost:3000/list',
                update: 'http://localhost:3000/update',
                destroy: 'http://localhost:3000/delete'
            },

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'audios',
                totalProperty  : 'total',
                successProperty: 'success'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json'
            }       

        }


    });
```

model :

```
Ext.define('LU.model.Audio', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 
        { name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        { name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'path', type: 'string'}
    ],

});
```

view :

```
Ext.define('LU.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mainview',
    id: 'main',





    initComponent: function() {

        this.items = [{

        }, {
            xtype: 'grid',
            title: 'Audio liste',
            store: 'Audios',
            id: 'mygrid',

            columns: [
                {text: 'Dateiname', dataIndex: 'name'},
                {text: 'Dateipfad', dataIndex: 'path'}
            ],
            listeners : {
                afterrender : function (grid) {
                        grid.addDocked({
                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            dock: 'top',
                            items: [{
                                text: 'Delete',
                                action: 'delete'
                            }, {
                                text: 'Download'
                            }]
                        });
                    }

            },

        }
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

and controller :

```
Ext.define('LU.controller.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views:  ['Main'],
    stores: ['Audios'],
    models: ['Audio'],

    init: function() {
        this.control({

        'mainview button[action=delete]': {
                click: this.delete
        }


        });

    },

    delete: function () {
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('mygrid');
        var row = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

        Ext.getStore("Audios").remove(row);


    },



});
```

and the server :

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
});



connection.connect();
connection.query('USE diktierserver');

app.use(express.bodyParser()); 


app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    if(req.method.toLowerCase()==='options'){
        res.send(200);
    }else{
        next();
    }
});
app.delete('/delete', function (req,res) {

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Content-Type','text/plain; charset=UTF8');

        console.log(req);
        var id = req.params.id;

        connection.query('DELETE FROM audio WHERE id = ' + id +'', function (err,result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(name + 'deleted');
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify());
    });

});
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Ext.data.proxy.Rest`, the default `actionMethod` for delete/remore actions is the HTTP DELETE verb. Therefore, you should ensure that your web server settings allow this HTTP verb. I've encountered issues where some load balancers don't even implement the DELETE verb, making utilization of the default action in the Rest proxy impossible.

You can, of course, change the VERB sent through on DELETE actions. You could change it to a PUT, for example, and still get the same [indempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) behavior as the DELETE.

Comment: thank you for you advice ,  just found out what the problem was while i tried to change the VERB. on my server i forgot to add ":id" to the delete path, so it should like like this app.delete('/delete/:id', function (req,res) { }